# QT Console Application appears in Application Output panel instead of Console Window

Tags: qt, console

I would like to have my application output to be opened into a new console window.

Currently it opens in the Application Output pane as show in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770211/qdebug-qt-console-application-to-output-to-qt-creator-application-output)

**.pro file** for what it's worth

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = console_app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
```

(How) Can this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811319/qtcreator-does-not-open-terminal-for-building

Comment: @Edward Weird. It was checked. Still opened in Application Output. Had to uncheck, clean, run qmake, rebuild. Still opened in Application Output. Go back, check again, then clean, run qmake, rebuild. Volia, it opens in new terminal. Confirmed this "bug" with a new console application. Same issue.